# Understanding reduceByKey function definition Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The `reduceByKey` function for a `Pair RDD` in spark has the following definition:

```
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

I understand that `reduceByKey` takes the argument function applies it to the values of the keys. What I am trying to understand is how to read this definition where the function is taking 2 values as an input i.e. `(V, V) => V`. Shouldn't it be `V => V`, just like the `mapValues` function where the function is applied on the value V to yield U which is a value of same or different type:

```
def mapValues[U](f: (V) ⇒ U): RDD[(K, U)]
```

Is this because `reduceByKey` is applied to all the values (for the same key) at once, and `mapValues` is applied to each value (irrespective of the key) one at a time?, in which case shouldn't it be defined as something like `(V1, V2) => V`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...Shouldn't it be V => V, just like the mapValues...

No, they are totally different. Recall that there is an invariant in `map` functions, they return an `Iterable` (`List`, `Array`, etc.) with the same `length` as the original list (the mapped one). On the other hand, `reduce` functions **aggregate** or **combine** all elements, in this case the `reduceByKey` combine pairs or values by the applied function, this definition comes from a mathematical concept called [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#MapReduce). You can see it this way, you combine the two first elements of a list by the applied function and the result of that operation, which should be of the same type of the first elements, is operated with the third and so on, until you end up having one single element.

Answer (score 1):

mapValues transform each second part of the pairs in the RDD applying f: (V) ⇒ U while reduceByKey reduce all pair with the same key to one pair applying f: (V, V) => V

```
val data = Array((1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(3,7))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd.mapValues(x=>x+1).collect
// Array((1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(3,6),(3,8))
rdd.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
// Array((1,7),(3,12))
```